# How do you set both port and thread pool using embedded jetty, v 9.1.0

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I'm using jetty 9.1.0, embedded, and would like to set both port and ThreadPool. I see a constructor for each, but don't see how to use one of those, and then any way to set the other.

doing this

```
Server server = new Server(9090);
```

or

```
Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(100, 10));
```

but there's no setPort or setThreadPool on Server.

Answer (score 10):

```
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
threadPool.setMaxThreads(500);

Server server = new Server(threadPool);

ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config));
http.setPort(81);

server.addConnector(http);
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't test it right know, but I assume you can

a) Use a configuration file and load it

or

b) Use the QueuedThreadPool and do the following:

```
 SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
 connector.setPort(9090);
 server.addConnector(connector);
```

Comment: Looks like in the version I have, it's ServerConnector, I don't see a SelectChannelConnector, but using ServerConnector may work, I'll give you credit once I try it out. Thanks!

Comment: For jetty 9, it's a bit different. I found a good example [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java)

Answer (score 3):

```
    Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(128, 8));
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory());

    connector.setPort(8897);
    server.addConnector(connector);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with [XML configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax) from /etc/jetty.xml file, which is well documented and also use beans with [Spring configuration](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.2.v20140723/frameworks.html).

There's no constructor that will take ThreadPool and port together.